# In jQuery datatables, how to get and set the column ordering at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to get the column ordering at any time during the runtime of my application. For example, suppose I have a table like this :

```
Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 | Header 5
--------------------------------------------------
```

Now at this moment I want to get the ordering of the columns, like an array(or array of objects) : `[Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5]`

So that, if I reorder the columns at any time like this :

```
Header2 | Header3 | Header4 | Header1 | Header 5
--------------------------------------------------
```

I should be able to get the updated column state array : `[Header2,Header3,Header4,Header1,Header5]`
And I should be able to set the column ordering state using this array.

Till now, I have been unable to figure out how to achieve this using jQuery Datatables. Any help would be great.

Comment: [Multi-column ordering](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html)

Comment: @davidkonrad i was using the ColReorder plugin, but all it has an api to set column order by array of indexes, and no api to get the current column ordering state

Comment: @ozil I am not looking for ordering of data, but the ordering of column headers

Comment: You realize `fnOrder()` returns an array of current ordering?

Comment: according to [this doc](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()), order (previously fnOrder?) returns the data ordering (asc/desc) from the table.. what i need is the order in which the columns are there

Comment: I am not referring to `order`, I am referring to `fnOrder()` and ColReorder, which you claim to have used.

Comment: @davidkonrad then after initializing the datatable, how to set the order by `fnOrder` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current column order using this:

```
var table = $('#timely_datatable').dataTable();
var colReorder = new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder( table );
var curr = colReorder.fnOrder();
```

`curr` will be something like: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Just make sure the table exists before you call this function.

Comment: thanks! I figured it out earlier but still will accept your answer :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out.